# right click "run-ing" in intellij runs TestNG not main

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

I have IntelliJ 2019.3, on my computer when I right click, the run menu says "run MyClassName.main" but for my coworker, right click running (or hitting the play run button) says "run MyClassName" and proceeds to skip main and just run the TestNG tests within the class (using Intellij's com.intellij.testng runner).  What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that with a "fresh" project, when you first right click to run a class, it gives you the option "TestNG or main?" and which ever one you first select, you can never select the other one "forever", it only shows one from then on.  So to get back the options, remove your *.iml and .idea files to reset project preferences.  Or go to "run [menu] -> edit configurations" and remove the existing ones.

[image]